# Fabricjs só me deixa rotacionar e editar somente a primeira imagem clicada

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Eu desenvolvi um código que implementa canvas, caman e fabricjs. O código tem como objetivo rotacionar imagem, editar cor e salvá-la quando eu clico em um botão. Funciona bem, mas somente com a primeira imagem. Quando eu clico no botão de edição novamente para exibir uma outra imagem, a tela mostra a imagem, porém não me permite editá-la. Em outras palavras, se eu clico na imagem, então a primeira imagem clicada aparece novamente para edição. Eu executei o comando alert para ver qual caminho o arquivo de imagem retornava.

Abaixo um trecho do meu código

```
TScript::create("
    temp_img_id = '{$id}';
    temp_img = '{$filename->path_filename}';

    var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('imgFilePreview');
    fabric.Object.prototype.transparentCorners = false;
    fabric.Object.prototype.originX = fabric.Object.prototype.originY = 'center';

    canvas.setHeight(500);
    canvas.setWidth(500);

    fabric.Image.fromURL(temp_img, function(objects){
        var obj = objects.scale(0.75);
        obj.scaleToHeight(350);
        obj.scaleToWidth(350);
        canvas.centerObject(obj);
        canvas.add(obj);

        $('.canvas-container').css({
            'width': '900px',
            'height': '900px',
            'position': 'relative',
            'user-select': 'none'
        });
        $('#canvas').css({
            'border': '1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204)',
            'width': '500px',
            'height': '500px',
            'left': '0px',
            'top': '0px', 
            'touch-action': 'manipulation',
            'user-select': 'none'
        });
        $('.upper-canvas').css({
            'border': '1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204)',
            'width': '500px',
            'height': '500px',
            'left': '0px',
            'top': '0px',
            'touch-action': 'manipulation',
            'user-select': 'none',
            'cursor': 'default'
        });

        $('#canvas').attr({'width': '500', 'height': '500'});
        $('.upper-canvas').attr({'width': '500', 'height': '500'});
        canvas.renderAll();
    });
");
```

Eu executo este código para fazer a edição de imagem. Eu uso o adianti framework desenvolvido por Pablo Dall'Oglio. Eu chequei qual o caminho que a imagem estava retornando. Eu já pesquisei no google e não achei nenhuma solução para isso.

Answer (score 1):

Você está fazendo a substituição dentro do TScript::create(), que é uma abstração da tag script. Então, para funcionar e fazer o PHP passar o "id" para o seu JS do frontend, procure atribuir a valor dentro de uma variável JS:

```
TScript::create("var id_imagem = " . $id .";");
```

Ou algo similar, e passe a ler ela do seu TScript inicial:

```
TScript::create("
temp_img_id = id_image; ...
```

Em caso de dúvida consulta o link abaixo:

[Passar variáveis PHP para JavaScript](https://www.visualdicas.com.br/programacao/php/2-passar-variavel-php-para-javascript)